# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1 | Pyspark

Tags: regex, pyspark

I'm trying to extract the district of some postcodes using regex with the following script in Pyspark:

`postcodes.select("raw_postcode", regexp_extract('raw_postcode', '^[a-zA-Z]+\d\d?[a-zA-Z]?', 1).alias("area")).show(40, False)`

I get following exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o562.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 44, ip-172-31-100-215.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 1): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:538)
```

I have tried the regex in Python alone and it works, but it is giving me trouble  in pyspark. Help me find out the reason.

Comment: Replace `1` in `, 1).alias(` to `0`. Try also with `'^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this one worked! simple and quick. Add it as an official answer.

Comment: Hi, you missed the groping the regex value.

Comment: @MenakaSankar OP did not miss it, there is no need to add any grouping construct here. That is extra overhead (although a very tiny bit) to the regex engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `regexp_extract` denotes the number of capturing group the contents of which you want to extract. However, your regex has no capturing groups defined, thus, you need to pass `0` as the second argument.

Besides, you may use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to avoid issues with escaping.

So, you may  use

```
postcodes.select("raw_postcode", 
   regexp_extract('raw_postcode', '^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?', 0).alias("area")
).show(40, False)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `[a-zA-Z]?` - an  optional ASCII letter.

Answer (score 0):

try Below pattern,

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?)
```

Comment: Note that OP regex only matches `abc12` in `abc123`, yours will match `abc123`. Besides, there is no need adding an extra outer grouping if it is possible to access the whole match directly, and it is possible.

Comment: Thank u for your explanation :)

Comment: @MenakaSankar You wrote an answer to explain what you don't know. Why would you do that?